# Is connection objects returned by multiprocessing.Pipe() shared in different processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

## Question

I created two sub-processes to communicate with Pipe. In the main process `parent_conn` is an actual parameter, I print the address of `parent_conn`. In sender() function `parent_conn` is formal parameter and also print it's address.

I found addresses are different, so they are different variables? Are there two pipes in this program? One is in the main process and anothor is in the sender() function. I think different processes don't share variable causes that.

- If so, why communicated in a formal parameter can affect the actual parameter? In other words, why sender()'s pipe can send data to main process's pipe?
- If not, in sender() function, `conn.close()` is runned. In main function, I find it's not closed when print `parent_conn.closed`. Why causes that?

## minimal runnable example

```py
import multiprocessing 
  
def sender(conn, msgs): 
    """ 
    function to send messages to other end of pipe 
    """
    print(conn)
    for msg in msgs: 
        conn.send(msg) 
        print("Sent the message: {}".format(msg)) 
    conn.close()

def receiver(conn): 
    """ 
    function to print the messages received from other 
    end of pipe
    """
    while True: 
        msg = conn.recv() 
        if msg == "END": 
            break
        print("Received the message: {}".format(msg)) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # messages to be sent 
    msgs = ["hello", "hey", "hru?", "END"] 
  
    # creating a pipe 
    parent_conn, child_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    print(parent_conn)

    # creating new processes 
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sender, args=(parent_conn, msgs)) 
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=receiver, args=(child_conn,)) 
  
    # running processes 
    p1.start() 
    p2.start() 
  
    # wait until processes finish 
    p1.join() 
    p2.join() 

    print(parent_conn.closed)
```

Comment: When programs lives in different processes they cannot share same instance of same object because they live in different address spaces, OS forbids such sharing for security reasons

Comment: I know it. Why sender() pipe can send data to receiver() pipe, they are in different processes  and cannot share same instance of same object as your description.

Comment: It serializes object into bytes during send and recreates from bytes during receive. Bytes are transferred using sockets on linux and using named pipes on windows. [Source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L519)

Comment: emmm, p1 and p2 in different spaces, they communicate by a pipe, do you mean so? But, the address of the `paraent_conn` in the sender() function and the receiver() function are different, how to explain that? A pipe have many ends?

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your reply, I understand it in the discussion with you.